# Linux Screen tab misbehaves on WSL environment

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Ubuntu 18.04 on a WSL system and usually log on a Linux server through ssh to get some work done. When I activate 'screen' and use the tab key to autocomplete commands, my cursor goes to the end of line, and the formatting of my entire terminal breaks from then on.
When using vim in that condition on a screen terminal, if I go to the end of file and press down on more time, it erases the last line from the terminal.

It seems a kind of misinterpretation of some terminal signal. When using Putty or any other ssh client under the same circumstances, everything works fine, so I am pretty sure it is a problem with WSL environment, specifically.

Any ideas about what is the main issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across this same exact issue and it appears to be a possible bug with Windows Console and certain $TERM values.

I have this problem when $TERM is set to screen-256color. The problem went away after setting $TERM to xterm-256color in .screenrc

```
$ cat ~/.screenrc
term xterm-256color
```